# Are there any retail copies of Mass Effect 1 and 2 that don't install SecuROM?

Tags: pc, mass-effect-series, drm

I refuse to install SecuROM on principle. I bought Mass Effect 1 and 2 on Amazon for $12. Wikipedia says

> More recent versions of Mass Effect on budget prices (those available on EA classics and Steam) have SecuROM omitted

so I'm not sure if it will not have SecuROM or if that just means things like Steam with their own DRM don't have it.

Are there any retail copies of Mass Effect 1 and Mass Effect 2 which don't include SecuROM when you install? If so, is there any way to know if the copy I have includes SecuROM?

Comment: Andrew, I tried to play around with this question a bit to make it less localized to a specific retailer and point in time so that it has a wider application and is a better fit for the site. If you feel I've changed the nature of your question inappropriately, feel free to rollback my change.

Comment: Thank you! I wanted to emphasize asking about this particular one, and added it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless they actually went and published a new SecuROM-free retail image to make DVDs of and shipped those out to brick-and-mortar stores, AND issued a recall on earlier versions of the discs, I'd recommend you go with the assumption that a retail disc will come with SecuROM, which it will subsequently remove after activation once you update it over the internet.

Comment: So, does the Amazon copy include SecuROM? It isn't a retail disc.

Answer (score 0):

As the Wikipedia article you read says, the "EA Classics" imprint does not contain SecuROM.

The easiest way to check for the version you have would be to start installing the game, and see if it asks you to approve installing SecuROM.

Comment: My point is that I don't want to install SecuROM even temporarily. Also, having bought the Amazon version, do you know if it contains this? I read that on Wikipedia as well and didn't know if it applied.

Comment: I can't remember any game with securom actually asking if I wanted to install securom. In fact, I remember a number of games failing to mention that they used securom at all.